# Installing Nvidia proprietary driver via terminal

Tags: nvidia

I've been trying to install the newest driver of Nvidia to see if i'll get better performance in games but i keep getting a black screen at boot that flashes (Switching to console doesn't work either)

Can anyone give me a step by step guide on how to properly install these drivers?

I'm running elementary OS 0.4.1 (64-bit) and trying to install "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-381.09.run"

Thank you for any help you can give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually adding `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` is not needed anymore, since Ubuntu 16.04 added tested and working NVIDIA Drivers long ago.
And using the lastest drivers, or compiling that "binaries" from NVIDIA webpage will spoil your system because they are not tested by the Ubuntu team. So using `nvidia-381`(as far as I know is the newest driver released) is not recommended and It may cause you an infinite loop black screen.

So I will recommend you to do **the most and eficient secure method**.

For making sure what driver your system needs.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

That command will tell you what packages you will need for using NVIDIA drivers.
Then just make sure to install this

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx
```

And that's all, note that I told you `nvidia-xxx` because you must enter the driver version displayed in `ubuntu-drivers devices` and I warn you updating the kernel may cause you problems, so once you installed that NVIDIA driver, please don't upgrade anymore, for updating just use `sudo apt-get upgrade` that command will hold new kernel releases.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Add the Proprietary drivers ppa

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

**Step 2 :** Update the repos

> sudo apt-get update

**Step 3 :** Install the nvidia driver 381.09 beta

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-381

or

> Go to the AppCenter > Updates -> install nvidia-381