# How can i use my graphic card?

Tags: graphic-drivers, graphics, processes

I have hp pavallion AU003tx with nvidia 940MX 2gb.
I have dual boot eOS and windows 10. 
When i right click  over applications in windows10 there is option to select the processor ( intel or nvidia) but in eOS everything is open with intel.
I need to run application in eOs with nvidia.
How can i do ? 
Is it possible that feature to switch processor in eOs?
Sometimes i need external processor when i am using kdenlive .

Comment: Must say this first...I have zero experience with nVidia cards. But, have you installed the appropriate nVidia drivers in elementary? The little I do know from reading is that the drivers are very critical. Have a look at this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12558/installing-nvidia-proprietary-driver-via-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open AppCentre and go to the updates tab. Wait some seconds til it loads everything and go to the Drivers section.
There install the latest nvidia driver (the one that has a higher number, in my case is 384, it may be different in yours).

When it finishes installing everything, reboot your system. Now go to Applications and search for "NVIDIA X Server Settings" and open it. You can now choose what GPU you want to use. Beware you'll have to logout and login again every time you want to switch GPUs.